# PHP Generators: How to always clean resources, even when break is called?

Tags: php, generator, yield

The output of this code:

```php
function gen() {
    $rows = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo "yield $row\n";
        yield $row;
    }


    echo "finished\n";
}

foreach (gen() as $v) {
    echo "val $v\n";
    // break;
}
```

is

```
yield a
val a
yield b
val b
yield c
val c
finished
```

With the break uncommeted is:

```
yield a
val a
```

So if I break the loop, the code after the loop in gen() function is not executed. I need clean some resources, but I don't know how to do it.

For example, here:

```php
public function getRows(string $query, array $pameters = []): \Generator
{
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);

    // bind pameters...

    $stmt->execute();

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $item = $this->something($row);
        yield $item;
    }

    $stmt->closeCursor(); // this code is not executed if a break is called
}
```

Or a function who reads a file and the cursor should be closed at the end:

```php
$cursor = openFileCursor('myfile.txt')
while ($line = $cursor->getLine()) {
    $item = someFunction($line);
    yield $item
}
closeFileCursor($cursor);
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you need a generator? I don't see any reason to use one here. Also don't throw exceptions yourself, let PDO do it for you.

Comment: @Dharman is right. Generator doesn't really fit here. You can still use one if you really want to, but it's kinda pointless. As far as throwing exceptions go, you can still throw an exception if it makes sense to do that. For example you have some specific exception that you want to catch and log or do something else with it.

Comment: I'm kinda curious, and I probably should have asked earlier, what is the trigger for "break" to occur in your use case?

Comment: Why you talk about the exception, PDO or if generator makes sense there? I added other example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just had a play with using try/finally inside of your generator block...

**Try/Finally always:** always execute the contents of the finally block, regardless of `break`

```
function gen(){
  try{
    $rows = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    foreach( $rows as $row ){
      yield $row;
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    // close your connections here, always
    echo "finally";
  }
}

foreach ( gen() as $v ){
  echo $v;
  break;
}
```

This will print either: `a b c finally` or `a finally` based on the break

---

**Try/Finally with Condition:** try/finally block with a check on some kind of condition.

In this example I've used `key( $rows )` as this will return `null` once the foreach has been sucesfully exhausted (ie full iteration) or a non-null on a "break"

```
function gen(){
  try {
    $rows = ['a','b','c'];
    foreach ( $rows as $row) {
      yield $row;
    }
  }
  finally {
    // condition to detect incomplete return (like a row/total counter)
    if( key( $rows ) !== null ) {
      // close your connections here, but only on incomplete generation
      echo "finally";
    }

  }
}

foreach ( gen() as $v ) {
  echo $v;
  break;
}
```

This will print either: `a b c` or `a finally` based on the break

Comment: the first version was better as it was actually applicable to the PDO case in the OP.

Comment: I believe the second pars is completely useless. you don't create a generator *to iterate over an array*. You just iterate over this array instead. You only use a generator in a situation when key() is not applicable.

Comment: I might leave it there because any kind of condition could be leveraged to detect the early termination, eg a limit/offset sql fetching 20 rows at a time when we know there are 100 records, a counter could be used to determin if the end of the set has been reached.

Comment: well the question is actually how to always clean the resources, not how to clean when break is called *only*. just for clarity

Comment: Thanks, this works. I don't know why people talk about other questions like the exception or why PDO or whatever. This question can be applicable to other situations. For example a function that read a file, each line is converted to something and it yields it. At the end, the cursor of the file should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

I do realize this is rather a generic question, and the other answer is a direct answer to it.

However, as this question is tagged with PDO and your actual example is about this particular API, there is a much simpler way to achieve your goal: given  PDOStatement is already traversable, you could write this function like this

```
public function getRows(string $query, array $parameters = []): PDOStatement
{
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
    $res = $stmt->execute($parameters);
    return $stmt;
}
```

then you could use it the same way as your generator function:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE salary > ?";
foreach ($db->getRows($sql, [0]) as $row) {
    // whatever
}
```

when the loop will be finished, this way or another, $stmt will be nullified and thus cursor will be closed automatically.

As a bonus, you could give this function a more generic name and use it for any query, INSERT or DELETE for example.

Also, an important note: if you are expecting a result set that big, consider using an [unbuffered query](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#mysqlnd), as otherwise your **RAM will be consumed** despite fetching rows one by one.